# open() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python

I'm trying to search sth using python.
Here my code:

```
if request.get().strip() in inte: #that's just to understand my script
subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe'])
else:
      webbrowser.open("https://www.google.it/search?q=",request.get().strip(),"&oq=",request.get().strip(),"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j0l3.1306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```

request = the textvariable got from an Entry widget.

I didn't understand others method such as API, so I did this that doesn't work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear: you're passing 5 arguments to your `open` method:

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.it/search?q=",request.get().strip(),"&oq=",request.get().strip(),"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j0l3.1306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```

You could format it properly using `str.format` or (lazy way without too much typing) keep the arguments like this, but just join the strings built into a `tuple`:

```
webbrowser.open("".join(("https://www.google.it/search?q=",request.get().strip(),"&oq=",request.get().strip(),"&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j0l3.1306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")))
```

that said, since you're using the same argument twice, `str.format` is the preferred way:

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.it/search?q={0}&oq={0}&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j0l3.1306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8".format(request.get().strip()))
```